# Compiling against static openssl lib on centos 7

Tags: openssl, centos, kerberos

The LMS-to-Cast plugin (source here - https://github.com/philippe44/LMS-to-Cast) on CentOS 7 statically links to a number of libraries including openSSL. At link stage I'm seeing the errors below referencing openssl and Kerberos. What is my next step, is this an issue with the makefile on my specific platform or do I need to install additional libraries?

Please let me know what additional information you need to help, I'm aware I know so little about this process that I probably don't know what is required for debug.

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_skip_confound':
>   (.text+0x206): undefined reference to`valid_cksumtype'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_skip_confound':
>   (.text+0x229): undefined reference to`krb5_checksum_size'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_skip_confound':
>   (.text+0x26d): undefined reference to`krb5_checksum_size'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x8fc): undefined reference to`krb5_init_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x918): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_resolve'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x932): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_close'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x946): undefined reference to`krb5_free_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x955): undefined reference to`krb5_free_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x98b): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_default'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x9bc): undefined reference to`krb5_sname_to_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0x9ea): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_get_entry'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_keytab_is_available':
>   (.text+0xa0a): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_free_entry'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xa81): undefined reference to`krb5_init_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xa9c): undefined reference to`krb5_free_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xab0): undefined reference to`krb5_free_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xabf): undefined reference to`krb5_free_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xb14): undefined reference to`krb5_sname_to_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xb2b): undefined reference to`krb5_cc_default'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xb46): undefined reference to`krb5_cc_get_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_tgt_is_available':
>   (.text+0xb6a): undefined reference to`krb5_get_credentials'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xc23): undefined reference to`krb5_init_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xc56): undefined reference to`krb5_sname_to_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xca1): undefined reference to`krb5_free_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xcb5): undefined reference to`krb5_free_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xcc9): undefined reference to`krb5_auth_con_free'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xcd8): undefined reference to`krb5_free_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xd1b): undefined reference to`krb5_cc_default'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xd35): undefined reference to`krb5_cc_get_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xdc5): undefined reference to`krb5_get_credentials'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_cget_tkt':
>   (.text+0xe2f): undefined reference to`krb5_mk_req_extended'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_validate_times':
>   (.text+0xfb5): undefined reference to`krb5_init_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_validate_times':
>   (.text+0xffb): undefined reference to`krb5_rc_default'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_validate_times':
>   (.text+0x1016): undefined reference to`krb5_timeofday'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_validate_times':
>   (.text+0x1024): undefined reference to`krb5_free_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_validate_times':
>   (.text+0x109d): undefined reference to`krb5_rc_initialize'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_validate_times':
>   (.text+0x10b7): undefined reference to`krb5_rc_get_lifespan'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_validate_times':
>   (.text+0x10d2): undefined reference to`krb5_rc_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1766): undefined reference to`krb5_auth_con_free'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x178e): undefined reference to`krb5_auth_con_init'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x17c5): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_close'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x17d9): undefined reference to`krb5_free_ticket'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x17ef): undefined reference to`krb5_free_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1837): undefined reference to`krb5_auth_con_getrcache'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x186b): undefined reference to`krb5_sname_to_principal'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1896): undefined reference to`krb5_auth_con_setrcache'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x18bf): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_resolve'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1a27): undefined reference to`krb5_principal_compare'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1a59): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_get_entry'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1b00): undefined reference to`krb5_init_context'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1b3d): undefined reference to`krb5_get_server_rcache'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1c30): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_default'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1c5f): undefined reference to`krb5_decrypt_tkt_part'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
>   (.text+0x1cbc): undefined reference to`krb5_kt_free_entry'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_krb5_free_data_contents':
>   (.text+0xb83): undefined reference to`krb5_free_data_contents'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_expand_block':
>   (.text+0x59): undefined reference to`inflate'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_compress_block':
>   (.text+0xea): undefined reference to`deflate'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_free':
>   (.text+0x13d): undefined reference to`inflateEnd'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_free':
>   (.text+0x15b): undefined reference to`deflateEnd'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_finish':
>   (.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to`inflateEnd'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_finish':
>   (.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to`deflateEnd'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_init':
>   (.text+0x272): undefined reference to`inflateInit_'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_init':
>   (.text+0x2f1): undefined reference to`deflateInit_'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_ctrl':
>   (.text+0x56c): undefined reference to`deflate'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_ctrl':
>   (.text+0x612): undefined reference to`zError'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_write':
>   (.text+0x829): undefined reference to`deflate'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_write':
>   (.text+0x8bc): undefined reference to`zError'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_write':
>   (.text+0x957): undefined reference to`deflateInit_'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_read':
>   (.text+0xa33): undefined reference to`inflate'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_read':
>   (.text+0xaaf): undefined reference to`zError'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `bio_zlib_read':
>   (.text+0xb20): undefined reference to`inflateInit_'

Comment: What version of OpenSSL? It looks like those some of those functions, like `krb5_checksum_size`, are part of a [Kerberos library](https://www.google.com/search?q="krb5_checksum_size"). Also see [Kerberos support?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.openssl.user/11299) on the OpenSSL Users mailing list. It says to compile with `-DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, version is  1.0.1e (-fips if that's also important?). I did come across that flag but wasn't certain how to use it, added to the end of  a list of "defines" like this: `DEFINES = -DNO_CODEC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DPB_FIELD_16BIT -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5`. Is this the correct usage?

Comment: You might try `no-krb5` or `no-krb` for OpenSSL. I'm not sure about the other libraries. The bad thing is in this case: OpenSSL 1.0.x does not warn of incorrect `no-XXX` options, so it could be hit or miss (OpenSSL 1.1.x changes the behavior). You will know when you got it because `OPENSSL_NO_KRB5` will be defined in `<openssl/opensslconf.h>`.

Comment: Sorry busy week, thanks for getting back to me. Tried these, both upper and lower case with no luck unfortunately. I've also tried adding the location to krb5.h to my CFLAGS as suggested here -  [link](http://devel.kannel.narkive.com/QszZoXpz/dopenssl-no-krb5). If only it were 1.1x I was using it sounds like I'd have a better idea of what I was doing wrong!